# Tu l'as jamais (ta femme) vue ?

Tags: oral

Bonjour,

Dans *Féerie pour une autre fois I* :

> -- Couche-toi Arlette ! Allonge-toi !...
>
> -- Ah dis, verte ! dis !
>
> Je peux pas m'empêcher de faire ma remarque !... J'aime pas la voir
> verte !...
>
> -- Je te la synthétise eh croquant !... Eh, verte ? vert ? qu'est-ce que tu connais ? **tu l'as jamais ta femme vue ?**

Il s'agit d'une scène où la femme du narrateur, Arlette, va poser nue pour Jules, son ami, peintre et sculpteur.

J'aimerais comprendre ce que le syntagme *ta femme* apporte à l'effet de sens dans ***tu l'as jamais ta femme vue***.

L'effet d'oralité est-il plus accentué ainsi ? Je m'attendrais à une formule du genre  "tu l'as jamais vue, ta femme ?".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C'est une rareté grammaticale, possiblement un hapax. La forme attendue est bien en effet :

***Tu l'as jamais vue, ta femme ?***

Fidèle à son habitude, Céline joue avec les mots.

Peut-être a-t-il fusionné *vue* et *nue* avec cette séquence :

***Tu l'as jamais vue nue ta femme ?***
→  ***Tu l'as jamais vue ta femme nue ?***
  →  ***Tu l'as jamais ta femme vue ?***