« jusqu'au moment où, le jugeant venu » : sens, syntaxe ; (Molloy, Samuel Beckett)

Mais comment serrer les jambes, l’une contre l’autre, étant donné leur
état ? Je les serrai, c’est tout ce que je peux vous dire. Un point c’est
tout. Ou je ne les serrai pas. Quelle importance cela peut-il avoir ?
Je me balançai, voilà l’essentiel, avec une ampleur toujours
grandissante, jusqu’au moment où, le jugeant venu, je me lançai de
toutes mes forces et partant, un instant après, en arrière, ce qui
donna le résultat escompté. D’où me venait cet accès de vigueur ?
De ma faiblesse peut-être. Le choc me renversa naturellement. Je
fis la culbute.

Il est évident que « jusqu’au moment où, le jugeant venu » signifie « jusqu'à l'instant où, jugeant le moment venu » ou bien «  jusqu'où, jugeant le moment venu »  et c'est de l'une de ces façons que l'on écrirait ça (il y a peut-être des variantes). Est-ce que la tournure utilisée dans Molloy serait acceptable dans le français courant moderne ?  Est-ce que cet amalgames de deux  références au temps en une seule serait acceptable ? Doit-on considérer le français de Beckett dans ce cas précis comme étant correct ?
Il est possible que ce soit l'usage d'un participe après « jugeant » qui induise cette notion de double concept ; elle disparait lorsque le mot « propice » est utilisé.

jusqu’au moment où, le jugeant propice, je me lançai de
toutes mes forces …


Quel est le problème? La phrase est grammaticalement correcte, le sens limpide. Donc OUI la phrase est acceptable. Trivialement. VTC.

@FrançoisJurain L'amalgame de un « moment quelconque » qui devient « un moment propice » dans un seul mot ne vous gêne pas ?

Je vois ça comme une formulation humoristique qui joue sur les attentes du lecteur. On s'attend à avoir l'élément déclencheur après le "où", mais on a juste "le jugeant venu". On perd cet effet en utilisant les alternatives, certes plus claires et plus lisibles (justement), que tu as données. Je ne pourrais pas expliquer plus que ça pourquoi mais personnellement ça me fait rire. Un peu dans la veine des "il est arrivé premier à un concours de circonstances" ou du style de Raymond Devos.

@TeleportingGoat Ça m'a complètement échappé, mais me semble ne pas être une des moindres possibilités (l'humour, d'une sorte ou d'une autre, fait partie de cette œuvre) ; ce point de vue, s'il peut être établi comme le seul valable, annule toute considération concernant la syntaxe, et donc vaut peut-être la peine d'une réponse.

Il a été démontré dans d'autres de vos questions sur Molloy que Beckett repousse volontiers les limites du langage, d'autant plus que son narrateur déclare lui-même avoir perdu tout sens de l'orthographe et des mots.
Ce n'est d'ailleurs pas limité à Molloy :

On note en effet chez Beckett de plus en plus la présence des figures de style qui
dans leurs caractéristiques se rapprochent des fautes grammaticales et qui plutôt que d’être
fonctionnelles font échouer la syntaxe et nous entraînent dans une lecture-spirale des
dysfonctionnements de la langue. Leur dynamique est celle de la « rupture de cohérence
morphosyntaxique » (Fromilhague et Thomasset, 1995 : 34)

Shoah à travers l'oeuvre de Samuel Beckett

Samuel Beckett : Dans ses pièces de théâtre et ses romans, Beckett utilise l’anacoluthe pour reproduire les hésitations et les ruptures de la parole, donnant ainsi une impression de réalisme et d’authenticité à ses dialogues.

Anacoluthe et littérature
Comme nous sommes en présence d'un auteur à la langue notoirement plastique, la liste de ses inventions et écarts de la norme est potentiellement gigantesque. Je ne pense pas, hors doute sérieux sur le sens, qu'il soit nécessaire d'ouvrir une nouvelle question pour chaque passage de son roman si la réponse doit toujours être la même : "invention de l'auteur" ou "opinion-based". Une seule question qui regrouperait quelques exemples d'illustration parait suffisamment éclairante et utile pour la communauté.

Il existe des quantités de questions sur Céline, qui n'est pas moins un auteur qui abuse la langue par facétie, et il n'a jamais été question de refuser les questions sur la littérature de Céline ; après tout chaque cas possède son individualité, sur laquelle il convient d'apporter des précisions quand à la qualité du tour, facétieux ou autre. Voir par exemple ce commentaire.

@LPH Je peux aussi prendre un Molière et créer une question pour chaque expression ancienne dans le texte en demandant si elle est encore usitée aujourd'hui... même si chacune est légitime individuellement, pas sûr que ça rentre dans les clous de ce qui est acceptable sur le site. C'est la quantité, le "flood" qui peut être dérangant.

@LPH Les questions posées sur Céline sont des questions de vocabulaire, elles sont sur le sens des mots, pas sur la syntaxe ou la grammaticalité ou agrammaticalité d'un auteur qui a exprimé lui-même vouloir prôner « littérature du non-mot » et parler du «  caractère contre-nature des mots » ( lettre à Axel Kaun, 1937, déjà cité), son personnage Molloy dit dans le roman éponyme  « tout langage est un écart de langage » Dans sa postface de Molloy aux Éditions de Minuit   Jean-Jacques Mayou parle longuement du style de Beckett [...]

[...] « Molloy est un langage, un nouveau langage », « peut-être le plus grand inventeur de langage de tous les temps », « il trouve la formule toute
faite, et lui fait subir une insertion qui la modifie et la renouvelle. » « L’effet de surprise marque l’écart par rapport au langage « normal » » « Un jeu constant déplace le sens entre la surface et le dessous dissimulé du langage. », etc...

@None Il n'y a pas que le vocabulaire qui pose des problèmes dans Céline ; voilà trois questions bien reçues qui sont à propos de syntaxe, et la dernière est très similaire à la présente question sur Molloy.
https://french.stackexchange.com/a/49936/17649 - https://french.stackexchange.com/q/52749/17649 - https://french.stackexchange.com/q/50098/17649

L'idée de double concept ne semble pas être exacte ; utiliser un adjectif  au lieu d'un participe passé semble rétablir quelque chose de naturel. Ceci pourrait correspondre au fait que « juger qqc + attr » ne tolère que des substantifs est des adjectifs (selon le TLFi).

(TLFi) C.4.
♦ [Le compl. est un subst. et l'attribut un adj.] Le plan du grand Cointet était d'une simplicité formidable. Du premier abord, il jugea le collage en cuve impossible (Balzac, Illus. perdues,1843, p. 744).Mon père, qui jugea cette jaquette encore trop neuve (Giraudoux, Intermezzo,1933, III, 3, p. 173):

... M. de Norpois, qui, pour raison de santé, devait depuis longtemps venir faire à Paris une petite cure, aurait quitté Berlin où il ne jugeait plus sa présence utile. Proust, Fugit.,1922, p. 639.


De plus « le moment venu » est une locution adverbiale, ce qui semble être la raison la plus probante pour laquelle le résultat de la couper sonne faux.

(Wiktionnaire
le moment venu
Au moment propice.
"En un mot, et pour me répéter, le moment venu, mon bonheur est là, et.... je.... le.... tiens!" — (Friedrich Wilhelm Hackländer, Le moment du bonheur, chap. 2, traduit de l'allemand par A. Materne, Librairie Hachette, 1869, p. 26

Cette tournure est similaire à celle dans « la bière, qu'il trouvait petite, moussait quand même beaucoup » ; on ne peut pas dire ça, « petite bière » est un bloc dont on ne peut pas séparer les parties sans changer le sens ; dans certains cas similaires, le résultat  n'est plus un changement de sens  mais tout simplement du non-sens.
Donc, la tournure de Beckett n'est probablement pas correcte ; il vaut mieux ne pas l'utiliser.
